# What is an exhaustive mapping of pyspark dataframe's datatypes to that of Presto's datatypes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, presto

I want to get a corresponding datatypes in Presto to the ones in spark. When the dataframe is of `pandas` type, I do so with the following code:

```
def pandas_to_presto_type(self, pandas_datatype):
        """Get presto datatype mapped to pandas"""
        if pandas_datatype == "object":
            return "varchar"
        elif pandas_datatype == "int64":
            return "integer"
        elif pandas_datatype == "float64":
            return "double"
        elif pandas_datatype == "bool":
            return "boolean"
        else:
            return "varchar"
```

However, I am unclear as to what would be the correct and exhaustive mapping like above when the dataframe is from `pyspark`?

Comment: In python, dictionary can be used for mapping.

Comment: @shaikmoeed
I am asking 'what' and not 'how'.

Are you sure what I meant by mapping in here?

Comment: `{'object':'varchar', 'int64':'integer', so on.. }` I'm talking about this. Is this not what meant here?

Comment: I am asking about the complete list that you have mentioned.

Comment: `__all__ = ["DataType", "NullType", "StringType", "BinaryType", "BooleanType", "DateType","TimestampType", "DecimalType", "DoubleType", "FloatType", "ByteType", "IntegerType", "LongType", "ShortType", "ArrayType", "MapType", "StructField", "StructType"]` This all Types are available. Ref:: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jegonzal/pyspark/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html